# What's missing to update this data-bound textbox? Why does it update if I use a MessageBox breaker?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a WPF project called WpfDataBindTests. With the MainWindow.xaml I've got this setup:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfDataBindTests.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfDataBindTests"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Name="myGrid">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the .xaml.xs I've got this

```
namespace WpfDataBindTests
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myGrid.DataContext = this;
            _name2 = "Start...";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private string _name2;

        public string Name2
        {
            get { return _name2; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name2)
                {
                    _name2 = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name2");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've then changed the app type to a console app and removed the App.xaml to redefine the Program class as the entry point:

```
namespace WpfDataBindTests
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
            x.Show();
            x.Name2 = "HELLO";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            x.Name2 = "THIS";
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            x.Name2 = "WORKED";
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that calling the `x.Name2 = "xyz"` lines do not change the text shown on the WPF window.

So far I've tried adding to the TextBox Binding paramter:
`RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}`
and
`Mode=TwoWay`, neither of which makes a difference.

**But if I add MessageBox.Show("") in between the x.Name2 = "" lines, the text on the form changes!!!** - So what's going on here that forces the refresh?

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainWindow x = new MainWindow();
        x.Show();
        x.Name2 = "HELLO";
        MessageBox.Show("");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        x.Name2 = "THIS";
        MessageBox.Show("");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        x.Name2 = "WORKED";
        MessageBox.Show("");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: My WPF is a bit rusty so posting this as a comment only rather than an answer as I could be wrong. Try setting `Mode=TwoWay`, `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: You need to set the DataContext on the Window, otherwise it has no clue where to look for `Name2`. You probably already get warnings about the binding in the VS debug output. In your case in the ctor of your MainWindow: `DataContext = this`.

Comment: If you set `_name2` to some default value, do you see it in the `TextBox`? How many instances of `MainWindow` are there?

Comment: @jamheadart: Did you try to bind using a RelativeSource as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: @mm8, but OP is not setting `DataContext` of main window, he is setting it on container (`myGrid`). It's unusual, but is it a problem?

Comment: @jamheadart: Please provide a full but minimal sample of your issue then.

Comment: I've deleted the question and redone it with the entire solution details - My `Program.cs` , my `MainWindow.xaml` and my `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

Comment: @jamheadart: Refresh when? And what's the thing with the custom `Main` method and `Console.ReadLine`...? You need to create an Application somewhere.

Comment: The method is to emulate how my actual application would be calling this. The Console.ReadKey() is just to pause before the app closes. I do not see "WORKED" when I remove all of the `MessageBox.Show` calls, I just see "Start..." as defined by the constructor. I do see each of the updates to the MainWindow whenever there's a `MessageBox.Show` break, which is obviously refreshing the window graphics somehow.

Comment: What I need to do is get that UI refresh without putting in a `MessageBox.Show`

Comment: Create an Application object. Why don't you start out from the default WPF template in VS? Then your code should work.

Comment: Because my project isn't a WPF application, it's a class library with WPF elements.

Comment: You need a dispatcher. See my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and answer. But I'm not sure how I can attach a Dispatcher to a WPF element that is in a class library rather than an app.

Answer (score 1):

> I've then changed the app type to a console app and removed the App.xaml to redefine the Program class as the entry point ..

Why did you do this? If you define your own custom `Main` method, you should create an instance of the `Application` class and call its `Run` method. This attaches a new `Dispatcher` instance to the UI thread, and then the `Dispatcher` object's `Run` method is called. This starts a message pump to process windows messages. You will need this to be able to see the updates:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.Run(new MainWindow());
    }
}
```

The `Run` method won't return until you shutdown the application.

If you use the default `WPF Application` template in Visual Studio and for example handle the `Loaded` event for your window, you should see the value being updated, e.g.:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myGrid.DataContext = this;
        _name2 = "Start...";

        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //wait for 2 seconds...
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        //...and then set the property
        Name2 = "new...";

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name2;

    public string Name2
    {
        get { return _name2; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _name2)
            {
                _name2 = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this just to test my class library. This library is compiled and distributed via installer, and is not a WPF application, it just uses WPF elements for display purposes. By creating a console app, I'm emulating what happens when the code is run via e.g. VBA instances.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a fix for my issue, I've gotten rid of DataBinding and just named my TextBox as "TBox" although I don't think that part was necessary, but I did remove everything in MainWindow including INotifyPropertyChanged

So my MainWindow.xaml.cs now looks like this and it works fine and dandy:

```
    private delegate void NoArgDelegate();

    private static void Refresh(DependencyObject obj)

    {
        obj.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle,
            (NoArgDelegate)delegate { });
    }

    public void LogoUpdate(MainWindow w, string m)
    {
        w.TBox.Text = m;
        Refresh(w);
    }
```